# Error installing JBoss BPM Suite

Tags: jboss, workflow, suite, business-process-management

I have no experience with JBoss BPM Suite I'd like your help.

I'm trying to install the JBoss BPM Suite, downloaded jboss-bpmsuite-6.1.0.GA-installer.jar file in the jboss site, to start the installation and performed the command java -jar jboss-bpmsuite-6.1.0.GA- installer.jar.
The program ran and asked to accept LICENSE later I informed the installation path, but it happened the following error:

"The required product.conf file in.:/home/user/ tools is missing or malformed Please supply Either an empty directory or an EAP installation"

I am unable to resolve this issue, someone help me?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You first have to install `EAP` server. Install it into your root folder with any name (`EAP-version`). After installing it then install `BPM` suite and provide the installation path the same as the `EAP` server and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the EAP server first. Download the desired version, and install EAP. 
Then you should define environment variables for $JAVA_HOME and $PATH (if they are not set).
Finally, execute 'java -jar /jboss-bpmsuite-.0.0.GA-installer.jar'

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder outside SRC where you have saved all the packages related to JBPM and provide the same path as of new folder. It will be resolved.